# Handling file upload via multipart form post in Loopback custom remote method

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, multipartform-data, loopbackjs

I've tried everything recommended in [How can I use body-parser with LoopBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523782/how-can-i-use-body-parser-with-loopback) and yet still no luck.

My client app is in AngularJS and uses the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) module, specifically like this:

```
      Upload.upload({
        url: apiUrl + '/Recipes/uploadImage',
        file: $scope.picFile,
        params: {
          recipeId: newRecipe.id
        }
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log('succes:', res);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log('error:', err);
      }, function(evt) {
        console.log('progress:', evt);
      });
```

On the server (Loopback) side, I have made sure that `server/middleware.json` has the middleware registered:

```
  ...
  "parse": {
    "body-parser#json": {},
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}    
  },
  ...
```

For good measure, although I'm not sure if body-parser is even needed in addition to multer (and body-parser is being required anyway because of being registered in `middleware.json`), I've included these lines in `server/server.js`:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(multer().any()); // for parsing multipart/form-data
```

And I've also installed both:

```
npm install --save multer
npm install --save body-parser
```

Finally, my custom remote method looks like this:

```
  Recipe.remoteMethod(
    'uploadImage',
    {
      accepts: [
                { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' }               },
                { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' } }
            ],
      returns: {
        arg: 'status', type: 'object', root: true
      },
      http: {verb: 'post'}
    }
  );
```

The actual function so far is just trying to get something to work with:

```
Recipe.uploadImage = function (req, query, cb) {

        console.log('params:', req.file, req.recipeId);
        console.log('body:', req.body);
        ... // And once I can get this I'm going to get the stream and pipe it to a remote storage container, but I need the file first!
```

The output from posted to the above is

```
params: undefined undefined
body: {}
```

**Which sort of suggests that multer isn't really doing its thing, and I'm not really getting the parts of the multi-part form post?**

Help!

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get things working more easily using `formidable`, but would be curious to know how to get the `multer` working properly as a middleware in Loopback.

Comment: You can get file uploads in loopback without having to add middleware by using a Storage component. Check out https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+component if you haven't already. We're using it in concert with ng-file-upload and Amazon S3.

Comment: But how would that help if you wanted to transform the file stream before piping it off to the storage?

Comment: It probably wouldn't, but if you just get the file on the server first with a quick setup of a built-in feature, might help. Then you've got the file on the server and you can do whatever you need transform-wise. Plus you have a backup of the original. But I have no idea about your real requirements or why you're transforming the stream, so it might not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if that help you. With upload and check information in loopback3.

/server/server.js

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(multer().any()); // for parsing multipart/form-data



app.start = function() {
```

/server/midleware.json

```
  "parse": {
    "body-parser#json": {},
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}
  },
```

final model:

```
module.exports = function(Offer) {

    Offer.add = function (ctx,options,cb) {
    console.log(ctx.req.body);
    console.log(ctx.req.files[0]); 
    if(!options) options = {};
    ctx.req.params.container = 'x';
Container.upload(ctx.req,ctx.result,{container: 'x'},function (err,fileObj) {

fileObj.files[''] ...
```

**and remote my is different then your**

```
 Offer.remoteMethod(
    'add',
    {
      description: 'Uploads a file',
      accepts: [
        { arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: { source:'context' } },
        { arg: 'options', type: 'object', http:{ source: 'query'} }
      ],
      returns: {
        type: 'object', root: true
      },
      http: {verb: 'post'}
    }
  );
```

I use postman to send data explorer do not allow for files.
Something explorer do some error.

with this options:
address: http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Offers/add?access_token=c6qlcG19lhEYp6C6CztcPHYKpXj2uA3qARMJU7nxBL3trjveHbxNTo0BsvV3vleO

type: POST

authentication: no authentication

headers: empty (default content type is included)

body: form-data with data you want to send

**How to configure storage connector to filter size and type of file loopback:**

```
      "storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "nameConflict": "makeUnique",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./server/storage",
    "maxFileSize": "5242880",
    "allowedContentTypes":["image/gif", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/webp", "image/x-icon", "image/jpeg", "image/svg+xml", "image/x-icon"]
  }
```

How to create relation for model and file in loopback?
How to save file info in loopback?
You need to have model in data base what save name of file.

```
        Container.upload(ctx.req,ctx.result,{container: 'x'},function (err,fileObj) {
cFile  =  fileObj.files[''][0];
    Image.create({
                 name: cFile.name,
                 type: cFile.type,
                 originalFilename: cFile.originalFilename,
                   offerId: 3,
                 container: "x"},
    function (err, obj) { ...
```

Comment: TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions  app.use(multer().any());

Comment: After that you can have problem Container.upload(ctx.req,ctx.result ...